# Cognos data source connection issue

Tags: cognos

I have automated the restart of the services in cognos using ansible. I have restarted all the service like dispatcher, primary cm etc.. but after restarting we are facing data source connectivity issue.Is there any specific reason behind this? this issue getting resolved when I again restarted the services manually.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of detail around the error that is received,  I can only venture a guess that when the product is started through ansible, not all the services come up.

Comment: When I restart dispatcher using Ansible...  I am able to restart the dispatcher... but after restarting i am getting data source connection error in oracle and tera data